install4j to avoid loading DLLs from installation directory
The Install4j (v8) executable (e.g. Client.exe) apparently loads DDL from the Windows system folder \System32\ as well as from the installation directory of our application. According to the audit findings, there is a risk that the executable will call a corrupted DDL provided in the application directory instead of the one from the Windows system.
Q: Is there any way to prevent "local" DDLs from being loaded?
I guess this is MS Windows default behaviour and we can only consider a locking mechanism on the installation folder (read-only). This would bring additional challenges as the application may want to write logs there...

install4j has received related updates in recent versions, so please try this with install4j 10.

meanwhile upgraded to install4j v10, same observation. process explorer still lists numerous ddl being loaded. According to the process monitor details [stack] some of the dlls seemed to be loaded in the context of java.dll, but not all. I run it with openJRE8. Any further ideas?

Of course numerous DLLs are loaded from various locations. What problem do you experience? That the installer would prefer a DLL from the directory where the installer is located to a Windows system DLL? That's what I was referring to.

Its a sightly different story, a customer complains about that the executable is loading DLLs, potentially also manipulated ones residing in the installation directory as well as somewhere else in windows system folders. This is regarded as security (audit) issue of our java application. I personally do not agree to that pov, but would like evaluate options to limit the DLL loading behaviour, if any. Our java application does not require DDLs apart from those being related to JRE itself of course. So, I finally understand that there is no chance to take influence the DLL loading behavior.
